# AASTEX631: I need onecolumn equation in twocolumn format, is it possible?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, aastex

I am using `aastex631` in twocolumn format. I have a few long equations (with cases) that should not be broken into multiple lines.

```
  \begin{cases}
     \left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon\left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,\dtc)\right] & \text{if $n$ is odd}\;. \\
  \left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon \left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,2\dtc) + 1\right] & \text{if $n$ is even} \;.
\end{cases}
 \end{align}
```

I tried many techniques to keep this equation in onecolumn format but no success with `aastex631`. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

## `onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid`

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex631}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dtc}{dtc}
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-2]
\onecolumngrid
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon\left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,\dtc)\right]       & \text{if $n$ is odd}  \;. \\
\left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon \left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,2\dtc) + 1\right] & \text{if $n$ is even} \;.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\twocolumngrid
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## `figure*` environment

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex631}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\dtc}{dtc}
\begin{document}
\section{title}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure*}
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon\left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,\dtc)\right]       & \text{if $n$ is odd}  \;. \\
\left(-1 \right)^n \epsilon \left[2 acf(H,n\dtc) +2 acf(H,(n-2)\dtc)+ \hdots +2 acf(H,2\dtc) + 1\right] & \text{if $n$ is even} \;.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try bracketing the equation with `\begin{widetext}` `\end{widetext}`.